# Need to change values in classes without changing its reference

Tags: c#, class, reference

I am currently making an application which tracks information on players and monsters for a tabletop game.

Currently I've got classes for "Monsters". This class contains information such as its name, maxHP, speed, attacks etc. I've managed to make a Database which contains the default values for each type of monster. What I currently need to do is make it possible to change things such as name (Monster > Monster 1, Monster 2 etc), change its HP, and some other things.

I understand that I need to make a copy of such, but I am uncertain on how to do this.

What I currently tried is the following:

```
 public class DatabaseService
    {
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public List<Monster> AllMonsters { get; set; }
        public List<Monster> ActiveMonsters = new List<Monster>();

        public bool RollForHP = false;

        //Main Database Service
        public DatabaseService()
        {
            Players = GetPlayers();
            AllMonsters = GetAllMonsters();
        }

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            AddMonsterByName("Goblin", 2);
            AddMonsterByName("Adult White Dragon", 1);
            AddMonsterByName("Duergar", 4);
            foreach (Monster monster in ActiveMonsters) { Console.WriteLine(monster.Name); }
        }

        //Converts the .json list with all players to Classes, which are then stored in the list "Players" if the "IsInParty" is true
        private List<Player> GetPlayers()
        {
            var path = @"C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\DndAdvancedInitiativeTracker\Logic\Database\Players.json";
            var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            var players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(json);
            List<Player> inPartyPlayers = new List<Player>();
            foreach (var player in players)
            {
                if (player.IsInParty == true) { inPartyPlayers.Add(player); }
            }
            return inPartyPlayers;
        }

        //Converts the .json list with all monsters to Classes, which are then stored in the list "AllMonsters"
        private List<Monster> GetAllMonsters()
        {
            var path = @"C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\DndAdvancedInitiativeTracker\Logic\Database\Monsters.json";
            var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            var monsters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Monster>>(json);
            return monsters;
        }

        
        //Adds a given monster to the "ActiveMonsters" list
        public void AddMonsterByName(string monsterName, int amountOfMonsters)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amountOfMonsters; i++)
            {
                List<Monster> DatabaseCopy = AllMonsters.Clone();
                DatabaseCopy = AllMonsters;
                Monster monster = DatabaseCopy.Find(x => x.Name == monsterName);
                Console.WriteLine(monster.Name);
                var number = CheckIfNameExistsInList(monsterName);
                monster.Name = monsterName + " " + (number + i).ToString();
                ActiveMonsters.Add(monster);
            }
        }

        private int CheckIfNameExistsInList(string monsterName)
        {
            var counter = 1;
            foreach (var monster in ActiveMonsters)
            {
                if (monster.Name.Contains(monsterName))
                {
                    counter += 1;
                }
            }
            return counter;
        }
    }
```

In the "DoStuff" Method, I try to add 2 goblins, then a dragon, then a goblin again. The first goblin is named to "Goblin 1" correctly, but the second loop fails, because the AllMonsters' name for goblins is now "Goblin 1" because of the reference type, therefore, the second "Goblin" search in AllMonsters is never found, and returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're copying your database (and doing so for every iteration of a for loop which is quite wasteful), but your current check code `CheckIfNameExistsInList` will always return `1` even if there are no matches in the list.

You can simplify your AddMonstersByName (and use a simple check for previous monster entries) as follows:

```
public void AddMonstersByName(string name, uint number = 1)
{
    var count = AllMonsters.Count(x => x.Name.Contains(name));
    for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        var num = count + i;
        AllMonsters.Add(new Monster(){Name= name+num.ToString()});
    }
}
```

This was tested in a simple Console App:

```
var dataService = new DataService();
dataService.AddMonstersByName("Goblin", 2);
dataService.AddMonstersByName("Dragon", 2);
dataService.AddMonstersByName("Goblin", 2);

foreach (var monster in dataService.AllMonsters)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{monster.Name}");
}
```

where

```
public class DataService
{
    public List<Monster> AllMonsters = new List<Monster>();

    public void AddMonstersByName(string name, uint number = 1)
    {
        var count = AllMonsters.Count(x => x.Name.Contains(name));
        for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        {
            var num = count + i;
            AllMonsters.Add(new Monster(){Name= name+num.ToString()});
        }
    }
}

public class Monster
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Was this helpful?